# Error when upgrading from 2.2.6 to 2.2.7

Tags: magento2.2.6

I'm trying to upgrade 2.2.6

When I run the web setup wizard I get this response.

Check Component Dependency

We found conflicting component dependencies.

Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.7 requires composer/composer 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.4.1].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.7 requires composer/composer 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.4.1].
- Conclusion: don't install composer/composer 1.4.1
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.7].
```

When I try the command line upgrade I just get memory errors due to forkbomb protection.

My composer version is 1.6.4 so newer than 1.4.1

The site is on shared hosting so I can't downgrade or upgrade composer.

Comment: Will deleting the `vendor` folder and running `composer install` and `composer update` fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I used a different `composer.json` file from a fresh install of 2.2.6 and added in the required extensions and the upgrade worked.